# Color shemes look different across Terminal, Vim and nano

Tags: themes, gnome-terminal, colors

I am trying to change color sheme of my terminal. I've found beautiful at [terminal.sexy](https://terminal.sexy). Here it is:

[image]

Color codes of this sheme:

```
! special
*.foreground:   #c5c8c6
*.background:   #1d1f21
*.cursorColor:  #c5c8c6

! black
*.color0:       #282a2e
*.color8:       #373b41

! red
*.color1:       #a54242
*.color9:       #cc6666

! green
*.color2:       #8c9440
*.color10:      #b5bd68

! yellow
*.color3:       #de935f
*.color11:      #f0c674

! blue
*.color4:       #5f819d
*.color12:      #81a2be

! magenta
*.color5:       #85678f
*.color13:      #b294bb

! cyan
*.color6:       #5e8d87
*.color14:      #8abeb7

! white
*.color7:       #707880
*.color15:      #c5c8c6
```

As you can see in the screenshot at the right side of the page shown some examples how JS and Fortran code should look in Vim using this theme.

I've set colors of my GNOME Terminal according to this sheme:

[image]

So, look how JS and Fortran code looks like in Vim editor now:

[image]

[image]

It's totally different from the example on the site. Looks like colors was swaped.

And Nano editor is affected too but colors was swaped another way:

[image]

[image]

Why colors in my terminal look different from the site examples and how to fix them?

UPD:
Also tried on Tilda terminal and XFCE Terminal. And tried different shemes from site. Colors always changing but swaping on a different ways and never as in examples on the site

Comment: `vim` has its own color scheme that it uses; if you `:set color ` (then press tab many times) you can view your available/installed vim color schemes - it doesn't use the terminal colors, but your chosen vim scheme.  I assume it's the same with `nano`    (a quick look at my config files for vim look like ~/.viminfo` contains my chosen default color scheme)

Comment: @guiverc It does use colors from terminal sheme. Just tested for Nano and Vim and both affected by changing color in Terminal color sheme

Comment: Sorry, no doubt mine is modified & thus different.  I have [in vim] `syntax on` & want it to my chosen `colorscheme` by default so comments appear as one [known] color, operators, operands & verbs are set colors & the background being [far] less transparent than I allow by default  (if I'm in a hurry, or need to focus I change my scheme to another to get no background bleedthru at all). In my setup, terminal color has no influence as I have a set colorscheme in `vim`.  It may be the default 'vim' config allows some influence as many things are undefined, you don't have syntax, or other?